# padding-left is working but padding-right is not

Tags: jquery, html, css, gsap

I have a scrolling timeline ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/abyk4gcj/4/)) and I've encountered an issue where `padding-left` is working to hide the timeline branch images on the left side of the timeline before it's scrolled over, but `padding-right` is not working to hide the branch images on the right side.

The method I'm attempting to use is that the branch image is inside a container `.event_line` which has `overflow: hidden` and the image has `padding-left` set to 100% until the section is scrolled to at which point `padding-left` animates down to 0%, revealing the image. This method works on the left side of the timeline, but not on the right.

What do I need to change in order for `padding-right` to hide the branch images on the right side of the timeline?

Comment: Did you tryied applying `box-sizing : border-box` ?

Comment: That hides the branch image, but it makes the image scale up as padding-left goes down to 0%. I'd like to keep the scale consistent.

Comment: correction: padding-right*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `float:right;` to your right image.

**OR**

Add this CSS in your CSS file

```
.right .timeline-item .event_line img
{
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `overflow:hidden` cuts off the excess on the right side. Since the right side of the timeline has the padding on the right, the padding is being cut off instead of the content.

Try animating `margin-left` on the right side of the timeline from `-100%` to `0` instead of animating `padding-right`. [Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hykse7h/1/).

Comment: @585connor Not if you go from `margin-left:-100%` to `margin-left:0`.  Did you look at the fiddle?

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Still, seems more like a workaround compared to Rajnish's answer. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: To me, it seems more natural, but there are many ways to accomplish the same result with CSS.